# Difference between a complete and almost complete binary tree (ACBT)

Tags: data-structures, tree

**A complete tree** is a tree in which every level is completely filled and **an** ***almost*** **complete tree** is a tree in which if the last level is not completely filled, and then all nodes are as far as left as possible. My confusion is in the following example of a binary tree:

```
            O
          /   \
         O      O
       /  \    / \
      O    O  O   O
     / \
    O   O
```

According to the definition it should be **an incomplete binary tree**, but it is **a complete** **binary tree**.  How is this a complete binary tree and why is it not an incomplete binary tree?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your example is a complete binary tree: a complete binary tree can have an incomplete last level, as long as all the leaves in it are pushed across to the left.

A **perfect** binary tree is a complete binary tree in which the last level is full.

An **almost complete** binary tree is a complete but not perfect binary tree. So your example is also almost complete.

The terminology is confusing, but an almost complete binary tree is also complete.

Comment: then what is an almost complete binary tree?

Comment: exactly what is the difference between complete and almost complete binary tree?

Comment: @Bramsh if it's almost complete then the last level is not full

Comment: isn't it same like complete tree? because in complete tree last level is also not full as in my example.

Comment: @Bramsh if it's complete then the last level *might or might not* be full. If it's almost complete then the last level *is not full*. Your example fits both definitions. The confusing thing to get your head round is that an almost complete binary tree *is complete*.

Comment: Is this inline with the material taught in the Cormen book Introduction to algorithms? They seem to say a complete binary tree is what you call a perfect binary tree, and an incomplete binary tree is the same as your description. I am finding it very confusing to work out what is actually correct.

Comment: The terminology is really confusing, it seems like it should be called an "Almost Perfect Binary Tree" not an "Almost Complete Binary Tree", considering it's fully complete not almost complete. So a Complete Binary Tree is either an Almost Complete Binary Tree or a Perfect Binary Tree.

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure where some of these terms are coming from... the technical terminology for binary trees that I've learned are **strictly binary**, **complete**, and **almost complete**.

**Strictly binary** trees are binary trees where every node either has two children or is a leaf (has no children).

**Complete** binary trees are strictly binary trees where every leaf is on the same "maximum" level.

**Almost complete** binary trees are not necessarily strictly binary (although they can be), and are *not* complete. If the tree has a maximum level of d, then the subtree containing all the nodes from the root to level d-1 is a complete tree. Additionally, if a node has a right descendant at level d, then its left subtree is a complete tree whose leaves are all at level d (all the "bottom" nodes of the tree are "as far left as possible").

From what I've been taught, the accepted answer would be incorrect in saying that "an almost complete binary tree is also complete." They're not. An almost complete binary tree would be complete *if* you removed every leaf at the tree's lowest level.

Comment: An almost complete tree is also a complete binary tree

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the confusion arises due to reading from different books. The explanation of a complete binary tree (CBT) (i.e., every level except possibly the last, is completely filled and all nodes are as far left as possible) is in some books referred as an almost complete binary tree and the explanation of [FBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327125/difference-between-a-complete-and-almost-complete-binary-tree-acbt/74558119#74558119) takes as an explanation of CBT and explanation of a strict binary tree takes as FBT.

They don't have any explanation of a strict binary tree or it is possible they don't have an explanation for FBT.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing things. Where did you get those definitions?

Definitions:

> a binary tree T is **full** if
> each node is either a leaf or
> possesses exactly two child
> nodes.

and

> a binary tree T with n  levels is **complete** if all  levels except
> possibly the  last are completely full,  and the last level has all
> its nodes to the left side.

Your interpretation of "complete tree" seems to be what is referred as a "**full** & **complete** tree".

Source: [Full and Complete Binary Trees](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/%7Ecs3114/Fall09/wmcquain/Notes/T03a.BinaryTreeTheorems.pdf) in Data Structures & Algorithms by McQuain

Comment: and an almost complete tree is actually complete tree considering my definitions ?

Comment: Yes. "Almost complete tree" is a specific case of "complete tree".

Answer (score 0):

An ACBT is a tree in which each node that has a right child also has a left child. Having a left child does not necessarily require a node to have a right child.

Comment: Do you have a reference for it? Is ACBT a [SIA](https://html.duckduckgo.com/html/?q=self%20invented%20acronym)?

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 3 years ago"*

Answer (score 0):

I like the following definitions.

Complete binary tree:

> In a complete binary tree, all the levels of a tree are filled
> entirely except the last level. In the last level, nodes might or
> might not be filled fully. Also, let’s note that all the nodes should
> be filled from the left.

Almost complete binary tree:

> An almost complete binary tree is a special kind of binary tree where
> insertion takes place level by level and from left to right order at
> each level and the last level is not filled fully always

So an almost complete binary tree is also a complete binary tree. The difference with a complete BT is that almost complete BT has the last level is not filled fully always.

Source: *[Complete Binary Tree Vs Almost Complete Binary Tree](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/complete-vs-almost-complete-binary-tree)*

Comment: The articles on Baeldung seem to be extremely well edited.

Answer (score 0):

[Almost complete binary tree](https://www.gatevidyalay.com/tag/almost-complete-binary-tree/)

A complete binary tree is a subset of an almost complete binary tree.