# What is the difference between complete binary tree, almost complete binary tree and perfect binary tree?

Tags: binary-tree

What is the difference between complete binary tree, almost complete binary tree and perfect binary tree?

In my institute professor told they are different but on certain sites they have been merged almost complete binary tree and (complete binary tree and perfect binary tree as same). Now I am very much confused so had to ask world's largest tech community. Please help. Thankyou!

Comment: Does this help ([cs.se] is probably a better place for this question in any case): [Is there a difference between perfect, full and complete tree?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/32397/is-there-a-difference-between-perfect-full-and-complete-tree/79464#79464)

Comment: Were definitions given or was it only mentioned that terminology might be inconsistently used?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between "Complete binary tree", "strict binary tree","full binary Tree"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359660/difference-between-complete-binary-tree-strict-binary-tree-full-binary-tre) or [difference between complete and almost complete binary tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327125/difference-between-complete-and-almost-complete-binary-tree)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in part, this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) states the following.

- In a complete binary tree every level, except possibly the last, is completely filled, and all nodes in the last level are as far left as possible.
- A perfect binary tree is a binary tree in which all interior nodes have two children and all leaves have the same depth or same level.

However, it is also pointed out that this terminology is not well-standardized.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes that's okay but what about almost complete binary tree then?